# bit functions in HibernateEntityQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, seam

**Is it possible to use bit functions in queries using Seam's HibernateEntityQuery?**

I've just inherited some code based on JSF, Seam & Hibernate. The existing DAO code makes use of Seam's `HibernateEntityQuery`, in particular its support for restriction expression strings.

This has worked fine so far, but now I'm tasked with adding a restriction to an existing query that takes into account a **bit field**.

The Java entity code is using an integer field to represent a set of "days", via this enum:

```
public enum WEEKDAY {

    MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(4), THURSDAY(8), FRIDAY(16), SATURDAY(32), SUNDAY(64) ;

    private int value;

    private WEEKDAY(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The integer value from this enum is stored into the entity in an `int days` field.

For example, if the entity contains MONDAY, WEDNESDAY AND FRIDAY, `days` would be set to `1 | 8 | 16`, which `== 25`.

Now I'd like to add a new restriction to the query so that (for example) I can ask for entities where days includes MONDAY OR SATURDAY: `1 | 32 == 33`, so in SQL, I would do:

```
select id from entity where (select days & 33) > 0;
```

Is there such a syntax for `HibernateEntityQuery`? I tried adding the following restriction:

```
entity.days & #{myQuery.bitwiseMeetingDays} > 0
```

which results in the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '&'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring the table to have 7 boolean fields rather than a single integer for "days". This makes command-line queries easier as well.

It would still be nice to know of a way to handle the bit-field query though.